# Flattening images to apply PCA

Tags: python, image, pca, reduction

I have a file of 100 images. I want to apply PCA to a training set, then use the results to get PCA scores for the images in both the training and testing sets.

```
image_matrix = []

for id_num in id_list:
    image_matrix.append(np.array(
        Image.open(".../Posters/" + id_num + ".jpg")).T.flatten())

image_matrix[0:5]
```

When I run this block I get

```
[array([94, 95, 97, ...,  0,  0,  1], dtype=uint8),
 array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([245, 245, 244, ...,  63,  64,  68], dtype=uint8),
 array([125, 123, 123, ...,  43,  44,  48], dtype=uint8),
 array([ 94,  91,  93, ..., 166, 166, 165], dtype=uint8)]
```

The error occurs when I try to fit PCA on the training dataset

```
# fit pca on the training data
from sklearn.decomposition import IncrementalPCA
pca = IncrementalPCA(n_components=10)
train_pca = pca.fit(image_matrix)
```

I get this error on the `pca.fit` line

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I believe the problem comes from incorrectly flattening the images. What is the correct method of importing the images into a matrix that PCA can be performed on?

Comment: The method you're using does indeed flatten each image. I think the issue is more about how you combine them into one data-set. Presumably the images are all the same size? if so, try `pca.fit( numpy.array(image_matrix) )` instead of leaving `image_matrix` as a `list`.

Comment: My images are all the same size. Unfortunately, I am getting the same `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` error when using `pca.fit( numpy.array(image_matrix))`

Comment: Are the images RGB or grayscaled?

Comment: The images are full color when I view them in the folder, so I assume RGB

Comment: maybe play with the `batch_size` parameter to ensure that it's smaller than the number of images

Comment: if there is no loss of infomration, it is better to convert them to grayscale, otherwise you can do PCA on each of the 3 channels and combine results